# Sufficient condition for open mappings $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ to be continuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions, continuity

In this problem, we strictly concern ourselves with functions $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Suppose that

$(\text{i})$ $\ f$ is open.

$(\text{ii})$  $\ f$ is injective.

Does it follow that $f$ is continuous?

If so, what happens if we change the condition to *locally* injective (a function is locally injective if for all $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ there is a neighbourhood $N_{{x_0}}$ of $x_0$ such that the restriction $f|_{N_{{x_0}}}$ is injective) ?

I'm aware that for continuous $f$, $f \ \text{open} \Longrightarrow f \ \text{injective}$ (this is "sort of" the converse).

I'm also aware that there are discontinuous open mappings, but these are usually *very* badly behaved, so I'm inclined doubt that there are injective or even locally injective examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Since $f$ is open and injective, $f^{-1}$ is a continuous injective map from $f(\mathbb{R})$ (which is an open set) into $\mathbb R$. A classical Real Analysis theorem says that the inverse of such a map (that is, $f$) is also continuous.